# How to save modified tree into disk using XML Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

Tried this below but I get a 0 file and this error.
print() on unopened filehandle OUT at C:/Perl/site/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 3036.

```
#!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $upd_file = "updev.xml" ;
my $main_file = "main.xml" ;

# get the info we need by loading the update file
my $t_upd= new XML::Twig();

$t_upd->parsefile( $upd_file);

my $upd_dev_id = $t_upd->root->next_elt( 'DEVNUM')->text;
my $upd_dev    = $t_upd->root->next_elt( 'DEVS');
my $upd_seg    = $t_upd->root ;

# now process the main file
my $t= new XML::Twig( TwigHandlers => { DEVS => \&DEVS, },
              PrettyPrint => 'indented',
            );
$t->parsefile( $main_file);
$t->flush;           # don't forget or the last closing tags won't be printed

open( OUT, ">$main_file") or die "cannot open out file main_file:$!";

sub DEVS
  { my( $t, $DEVS)= @_;
    # just replace devs if the previous dev_id is the right one
    if( $DEVS->prev_elt( 'DEVNUM')->text eq $upd_dev_id) {
      $upd_dev->replace($DEVS);    
    }
     $t->flush(\*OUT) ;  # print and flush memory so only one dev is in there at once

  }

close OUT ;
```

Comment: seems that I don't have enough reputation for editing your question, so please, read how to format the code: wrap your code with <pre><code> ...code.... <code><pre>; or alternatively put four spaces before all the lines. This will fix also the comments to become headings. Please, could you also add a 'perl' tag?

Comment: I've edited the question as @PabloMarin-Garcia suggested, and I've added the `perl` tag too.

Answer (score 5):

Probably your problem is that you have passed the filehandle not a filehandle reference.

```
$t->flush(\*OUT) # look at the '\'
```

Some suggestions for your code: in modern perl is better to use the three arguments open and indirect filehandles:

```
open (my $fh_out, '>', $out_file) or die "unable to open '$out_file' for writing: $!";

$twig->print($fh_out); # this prints to the filehandle
```

Another way of printing is stringify your tree with `$twig->sprint` and print to a filehandle as usual

```
 print {$fh_out} $twig->sprint();
```